# What does it mean if the center of a gas stove flame is yellow?

Tags: gas-burner

The gas stove runs on propane. As I understand it, it's normal (I read an article on this topic https://inspectapedia.com/plumbing/Gas_Flame_Noise_Defects.php). But I would like to hear the comments of those who work with gas.

Examples of such flames that I am talking about:

[image]

[image]

Comment: A concern in the bottom photo is that some of the vents have been plugged -- clean the burner.

Comment: Yellow indicates incomplete combustion. You get this when the burner is not getting enough air. You will also be getting an increase of CO. Most burners I have used have an air adjustment of some type. If you cannot get more air in you can cut the amount of gas, the effect will be the same on the flame but it will reduce the BTUs. Hint most of the burners I have worked with (old ones) will burn yellow for a moment after adjustment but will quickly go to blue.

Comment: the flame in the top photo isn't really a concern because the small yellow areas of the flame will have to travel through the blue areas, at which point they will be completely combusted. Since I have to assume the burner is designed correctly, this effect could be caused by moisture in the in gas keeping the temp slightly cooler away from the reaction surface. If it were too lean of a mixture, I would expect to see yellow throughout the inner flame junction, not just the meniscus.

Comment: @dandavis, Thanks for the answer. And how would you explain why there are such yellow centers only on one side of the burner? And when changing the burners in places (a stove with two burners) - the situation does not change. True, with a long operation of the stove (10 minutes or more), the yellow centers begin to cover the entire burner, but they are less bright than on the other side of the burner.

Comment: I suppose that would likely be wind-based. Certain combustion mixes can be marginally balanced on the three legs of fire (heat, fuel, oxygen) such that a tiny difference produces a large effect. As the metal pores heat they expand, altering the mix. The burner itself could be slightly crooked which could allow a different mix on one side than the other, or just the rush of gas from one direction into the circle causes one side of the circle to have different pressure and different combustion;  a Bernoulli effect of the inside curve having less distance than the outer.

Comment: @dandavis, Thanks for the answer. As I understand it, in princepe, is such a flame normal? There is no soot on the dishes, not even close. But I really don't understand why these yellow centers appear when everyone's flame is 100% blue.

Comment: According to the article you linked, it's normal and "healthy" for LP (propane) gas. A natural gas flame (methane) is supposed to be all blue. There's really nothing strange or concerning about your stove, afaict.